# How to label edge in GraphSharp wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, graph, graph-sharp

I'm beginner in WPF. I draw some graphs with Graph#. Now I don't know how to get labeled edges. I need help!

I tried this solution https://graphsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/72119, but it didn't work.

I use Visual Studio Community.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What code have you tried?  You can edit your question to add this information.

Comment: @Theresa I tried this solution https://graphsharp.codeplex.com/discussions/72119, but it didn't work.